# ml-engine predict argument parsing errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

After successfully deploying dozens of models where only the most trivial (one arg in/out) ever successfully return prediction results due to parsing and other argument errors, I went back to the official wide-and-deep model: 
[official wide and deep tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep)
and this:
[serving wide and deep tutorial continuation](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md)
to try to export, deploy, and predict on ml-engine. 
I cannot get any permutation of text or json arguments to pass parsing.
Here are some of my tests and the responses:

**1)input file content, text:**

```
25,0,0,"11th",7,"Male",40,"United-States","Machine-op-inspct","Own-child","Private"
```

**response:**

```
{"error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"Could not parse example input, value: '25,0,0,\"11th\",7,\"Male\",40,\"United-States\",\"Machine-op-inspct\",\"Own-child\",\"Private\"'\n\t [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=5, Nsparse=6, Tdense=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], dense_shapes=[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]], sparse_types=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"](_arg_input_example_tensor_0_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/names, ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_1, ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_2, ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_3, ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_4, ParseExample/ParseExample/sparse_keys_5, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_0, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_1, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_2, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_3, ParseExample/ParseExample/dense_keys_4, ParseExample/Const, ParseExample/Const, ParseExample/Const, ParseExample/Const, Pa...TRUNCATED\")"}
```

**2)input file content, json:**

```
{"age":25,"capital_gain":0,"capital_loss":0,"education":"11th","education_num":7,"gender":"Male","hours_per_week":40,"native_country":"United-States","occupation":"Machine-op-inspct","relationship":"Own-child","workclass":"Private"}
```

**response:**

```
{....failed: Expected tensor name: inputs, got tensor name: [u'hours_per_week', u'native_country',....}
```

**3)input file content, json:**

```
{"inputs":{"age":25,"capital_gain":0,"capital_loss":0,"education":"11th","education_num":7,"gender":"Male","hours_per_week":40,"native_country":"United-States","occupation":"Machine-op-inspct","relationship":"Own-child","workclass":"Private"}}
```

**response:**

```
{....Error processing input: Expected string, got {u'hours_per_week': 40, u'native_count....}
```

**4)input file content, json:**

```
{"inputs":"25,0,0,11th,7,Male,40,United-States,Machine-op-inspct,Own-child,Private"}
```

**response:**

```
{...."Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"Could not parse example input, value: '25,0,0,11th,7,Male,40,United-States,Machine-op-inspct,Own-child,Private'\n\t [[Node: ParseExample/ParseExample = ParseExample[Ndense=5,....}
```

I also tried with inner escaped quotes, various lists/arrays, etc.

Please tell me I just need to reformat my inputs in the predict request (and how) :)
-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current state of affairs, the choice between a graph that accepts JSON and one that accepts `tf.train.Example` are mutually exclusive, meaning, you have to export the graph slightly differently.

From the [serving wide and deep tutorial continuation](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md), change these lines from:

```
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
```

to

```
inputs = {}
for feat in INPUT_COLUMNS:
  inputs[feat.name] = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=feat.dtype)
export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(inputs)
```

For reference, see [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census), in particular, the `*_serving_fn` definitions in `model.py` (e.g. [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/8a349c10bc19c1fe42bd6bd83606cec3a23b8f76/census/estimator/trainer/model.py#L224)); that example also shows how to export a graph that expects CSV as input.

Another note, if you are using `gcloud` to send the requests (vs. a request library), the input data format is *not* the full body the request to send: `gcloud` constructs the request using each line in the file. So the body of an actual request sent to the server will look something like:

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "age": 25,
      "capital_gain": 0,
      "capital_loss": 0,
      "education": "11th",
      "education_num": 7,
      "gender": "Male",
      "hours_per_week": 40,
      "native_country": "United-States",
      "occupation": "Machine-op-inspct",
      "relationship": "Own-child",
      "workclass": "Private"
    }
  ]
}
```

while the corresponding `--json-instances` file will look like:

```
{"age":25,"capital_gain":0,"capital_loss":0,"education":"11th","education_num":7,"gender":"Male","hours_per_week":40,"native_country":"United-States","occupation":"Machine-op-inspct","relationship":"Own-child","workclass":"Private"}
```

`gcloud` takes the contents of each line and stuffs them into the array shown in the "actual" request above.

Comment: I modified your code update to account for 'INPUT_COLUMNS' like this:

`inputs = {}
for feat in deep_columns:
    print(feat.name)
    if "indicator" in feat.name or "embedding" in feat.name:
        datatype = tf.string
    else:
        datatype = feat.dtype
    name = feat.name
    name = name.replace('_indicator', '')
    name = name.replace('_embedding', '')
    print(name)
    inputs[name] = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=datatype)
export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(inputs)`

and got a result, thank you!